# Reversing a Uri variable

Tags: android, uri

I am trying to reverse a Uri's order.

The Uri accesses the phones call logs

```
Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
```

but it stores them from oldest to newest while I want the opposite.

I tried using

```
Collections.reverse
```

but that only works for arrays.

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can input sorting option when you use ContentResover's query function.

query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
Query the given URI, returning a Cursor over the result set.

```
    public static Cursor getAllCallLogs(ContentResolver cr) {
    // reading all data in descending order according to DATE
    String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
    Uri callUri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
    Cursor curCallLogs = cr.query(callUri, null, null, null, strOrder);
    return curCallLogs;
}
```